# Adding class to the section once the section reach the top of the window

Tags: javascript

I am facing challenges in once the section reaches the top of the window that section add one class, anyone has the answer please share with me.

Comment: please vote if my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `scrollSpy`, `Bootstrap` has one built in you could easily implement without having to reinvent the wheel.

In short, the solution lies within comparing the `window.scrollTop` to the position of the `element` you are interested in. This usually has `top` and an `offsetX` which you can use to calculate how far up you are in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
        var element_offset_top = $('#mainFooter').offset().top;
        if (scroll_top >= element_offset_top) {
            $('#mainFooter').addClass('classname');
        } else {
            $('#mainFooter').removeClass('classname');
        }
    });
});
```

I used element with id="mainFooter" for this example code. also "classname" is your desired class name.